# Run equal height script on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that currently creates equal height divs on page load.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.fn.equalHeight = function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    return this.each(function(index, box) {
        var boxHeight = $(box).height();
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, boxHeight);
    }).height(maxHeight);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.group .module').equalHeight();
});
    </script>
```

Is there any way to have this run on window resize as well? So if a user already has a page that is loaded, but resizes the same calculations would occur and divs would be adjusted?

Comment: window has an "onresize" event.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);` this is what I've been trying to configure into this to this point. Is that what you're referring to?

I'm not quite sure how to apply it though. I've had little success.

Comment: Invoke the same plugin within window.resize.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // Do your positioning here
})
```